# Create generic interface that accepts type of objects as arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I have the following:

```js
interface Pet {
  a: A,
  b: B[]
}

interface NotPet {
  a: A,
  b: B
}

interface A {
  desc: string
}
interface B {
  name: string
}

interface DataStore<T> {
  addItem(type: T[keyof T]);
}

class Shop implements DataStore<Pet> {
  addItem(type: Pet[keyof Pet]) {
    //add type A or add type B
  }

  passToAddItem(itemToPass: A | B) {
    this.addItem(itemToPass); //<-- this expects either A | B[]
  }
}

class OtherShop implements DataStore<NotPet> {
  addItem(type: NotPet[keyof NotPet]) {
  }

  passToAddItem(itemToPass: A | B) {
    this.addItem(itemToPass); //<-- this works just fine
  }
}
```

The issue is highlighted above. I would like generic method to accept either A | B.. But in its current form it accepts A | B[].

I am wanting to be able to either pass A or B (not B[]) to the addItem method. I understand why it is expecting an array, but not sure how to resolve this.

The error I am getting is from the IDE: the Argument of type 'B' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A | B[]'.

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? As-is, it's hard to answer your question, since there's no error message, and the code can't be recreated since there's no `Pets` type.

Comment: Thanks.. updated. let me know if you have any other questions..

Comment: What's the rule supposed to be here? If you have a value then maintain the value but if you have an array then use the value type of the array? What about objects?

Comment: hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what are you expecting it to do, it does exactly what you asked it, which is to bind the T type to one of the member's types of T, and like you said you understand that.
so the solution is either:

1. change the Pet interface.
2. change the Shop class to pass B as B[].
3. use this.addItem(itemToPass as any);.

I really do not like 2. and 3.

Edit:
Sorry that i toke so long to answer again, work kids and life :)
any way after reading the comments it seems to me that your design is
a bit off you can solve it by using:

```
class Shop implements DataStore<NotPet>, Pet {
a: A;
b: B[];
addItem(type: NotPet[keyof NotPet]) {
    //add type A or add type B
}

passToAddItem(itemToPass: A | B) {// or you just directly use addItem
  this.addItem(itemToPass); //<-- this now works
}
}
```

Comment: It seems OP wants to convert `T[]` to `T` - that is, to only accept plain items, rather than arrays of items.

Comment: As VLAZ says.  Although, it's not that I want to 'convert' it.. I want the method signature to only accept inputs of a type that CAN be added to the array at a later stage.